# Thickness of the cubic lattice graph

Tags: graph-theory

By "cubic lattice graph" I mean that graph you get when you put vertices at integer coordinates $(x,y,z)$ in 3D space, and put edges between nearest neighbours.

Given the above the description, you can see that this graph feels very 3D to me. So I was surprised to learn in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2503058_The_Thickness_of_Graphs_A_Survey) that any graph with maximum degree 6 has a maximum thickness of three. This means that the cubic lattice graph (which has degree six for all vertices) can essentially be represented as a stack of three planar graphs.

I have yet to find a description of how this miracle can be performed. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think the survey you cite deals with finite graphs. Any finite subgraph of the lattice graph is even the union of two planar ones: put the edges of two directions into one graph, and the third direction to the other.

Comment: Ah yes, good point!

Comment: As Ilya Bogdanov said, two planes would do. Set vertices with the even sum of coordinates on one plane, and with the odd sum of coordinates on another plane. Etc. ########## This will work in arbitrary dimension, it may be higher than 3.

Comment: @WlodAA Sorry, I do nit understand your construction. You need to split all *edges* into severL planar graphs.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov, thank you.